# Query execution is slow in PL/SQL anonymous block

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

The query runs slow in Oracle PL/SQL.  It takes about 8 minutes in PL/SQL whereas it takes only 4 seconds when run in SQL Editor or SQL Plus.

Please let me know what is causing this.  Is it possible that a different execution plan is picked up by SQL and PL/SQL ?

```
----SQL Editor query---takes 4 seconds---400 row count--
SELECT count(*) FROM
(
SELECT col1, col2
FROM
my_tab1 t1, my_tab2 t2
WHERE
t1.pk_col1=t2.pk_col1
and t1.created_date < t2.created_date
)


--PL/SQL Code--takes about 8 minutes---400 row rount--
DECLARE 
v_cnt   PLS_INTEGER:=0;
BEGIN
SELECT count(*) INTO v_cnt 
FROM
(
SELECT col1, col2
FROM
my_tab1 t1, my_tab2 t2
WHERE
t1.pk_col1=t2.pk_col1
and t1.created_date < t2.created_date
)

END;
/
```

Comment: It should take a little longer in PL/SQL due to context switching from PL/SQL to SQL but that shouldn't go till 8 Minutes. Can you please try both the queries after clearing your result_cache.

Comment: Thanks, @AnkitBajpai.  There are background processes running.  Please advice how can I clear RESULT_CACHE so it doesn't impact other processes

Comment: Result_cache is unlikely to be making pl/sql slower (there are some very internal mechanics that might make it slower but not to the degree you’re seeing). I would start by checking the execution plans, this sort of time difference suggests something very different is occurring. Look up your sql_ids by searching v$sql on sql_text (the pl/sql one will be all capitalised) and use dbms_xplan.display_cursor (with null child number)

Comment: Thanks, @AndrewSayer.  How do I capture the explain plan in PL/SQL? any tips or links that I can refer?

Comment: You need to look at the execution plan, not the explain plan. I explained (pun intended) how to do this: find the `sql_id` for the statements in `v$sql` and grab the plan with `dbms_xplan.display_cursor`

Comment: @AnkitBajpai context switching for one SQL statement will be in microseconds. Compiling the anonymous block will take longer and may be in the low hundredths of a second. I wouldn't expect either to be relevant when investigating an 8 minute difference.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson, That's what my first line is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to capture the execution plan within an anonymous block is to call `dbms_xplan.display_cursor` in a loop and print each line of output:

```
declare
    v_cnt pls_integer;
begin
    execute immediate 'alter session set statistics_level = ALL';

    select count(*) into v_cnt 
    from
    (
        select col1, col2
        from   my_tab1 t1, my_tab2 t2
        where  t1.pk_col1 = t2.pk_col1
        and    t1.created_date < t2.created_date
    );

    for r in (
        select p.plan_table_output
        from   table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(null,null,'ALLSTATS LAST -OUTLINE +NOTE +PREDICATE +IOSTATS +REPORT')) p
    )
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line(r.plan_table_output);
    end loop;
end;
```

You can make the same call from a SQL*Plus command prompt immediately after executing a SQL statement, but you first have to disable dbms_output, as otherwise the SQL statement is not the 'last' statement you made. (You can also specify the sql_id if you know it.) For more details see the [dbms_xplan documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/arpls/DBMS_XPLAN.html).

```
set serverout off

alter session set statistics_level = ALL;

select count(*)
from
(
    select col1, col2
    from   my_tab1 t1, my_tab2 t2
    where  t1.pk_col1 = t2.pk_col1
    and    t1.created_date < t2.created_date
);

select p.plan_table_output
from   table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(null,null,'ALLSTATS LAST +OUTLINE +ADAPTIVE +PARTITION +NOTE')) p;
```

For a handy script to call this in one line, see [www.williamrobertson.net/documents/xplanx.html](https://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/xplanx.html). Then it's just

```
select count(*)
from
(
    select col1, col2
    from   my_tab1 t1, my_tab2 t2
    where  t1.pk_col1 = t2.pk_col1
    and    t1.created_date < t2.created_date
)

@xplanx
```